# How to reference to root controller from another area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a url.action url inside the settings area. I need to specify the root controller which is outside of the settings area.

How can I specify it inside the url.action?

[image]

Comment: Is specifying it in `new { area = "areaName"}` part of your Url.Action constructor a solution?

Comment: The root controller dose not have an area i guess.  new { area = "areaName"}This is only used if there is a new area created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that new { area = ""} empty dose reference to the root. So from e.g inside another area this would be redirect to root controller/action